# Haskell: can't match expected type Either

Tags: haskell, types, type-mismatch

I have the following code, where I try to have the function `eval3` return an `Int` or `Bool`, but I get an error message:

```
• Couldn't match expected type ‘Either Int Bool’
              with actual type ‘Int’

• In the expression: eval e2

  In the expression: if eval0 e1 then eval e2 else eval0 e3

  In an equation for ‘eval3’:

      eval3 (If e1 e2 e3) = if eval0 e1 then eval e2 else eval0 e3
```

error:

```
• Couldn't match expected type ‘Either Int Bool’
              with actual type ‘Bool’

• In the expression: eval0 e3

  In the expression: if eval0 e1 then eval e2 else eval0 e3

  In an equation for ‘eval3’:

      eval3 (If e1 e2 e3) = if eval0 e1 then eval e2 else eval0 e3


{-# LANGUAGE TypeSynonymInstances, FlexibleInstances #-}

data Exp = V Var
    | B Bool
    | L Exp
    | A Exp Exp
    | MyInt Int
    | And Exp Exp
    | If Exp Exp Exp
data Var = VZ |VS Var

eval :: Exp -> Int
eval (MyInt e1)     = e1

eval0 :: Exp -> Bool
eval0 (B e1) = e1


eval3 :: Exp -> Either Int Bool
eval3 (If e1 e2 e3) = if eval0 e1 then eval e2 else eval0 e3
```

What do I need to add or change to get the function `eval3` to return either type

Comment: `eval` returns an `Int` but `eval e2` needs to return an `Either Int Bool` per the definition of `eval3` so that's the first error. So you need to use one of the `Either` constructors to wrap your `Int`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We do not return either type, but rather the `Either` type.

To construct a value of type `Either Int Bool` either use `Left i` where `i :: Int` or `Right b` where `b :: Bool`. In your case,

```
eval3 :: Exp -> Either Int Bool
eval3 (If e1 e2 e3) = if eval0 e1 then Left (eval e2) else Right (eval0 e3)
```

since you have

```
eval :: Exp -> Int       -- eval (e2 :: Exp) :: Int

eval0 :: Exp -> Bool     -- eval0 (e3 :: Exp) :: Bool
```